# Java SDK Authentication with VersionOne Access Tokens

Tags: java, access-token, versionone

I am trying to authenticate against my VersionOne instance using the V1 Java SDK and V1 access tokens. I followed the documentation for [creating acess tokens](http://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/API_Authentication/Access_Token_Authentication) and [creating a connection](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/Java_SDK/Creating_a_Connection) in preparation to get this to work.

The problem is that I keep running into a ConnectionException stating a "401 Could not authenticate" message (stack trace below). What could be causing this?

---

**Development Environment**

1. VersionOne Winter '15 (15.0.13.7283) using Windows Integrated Authentication
2. VersionOne.SDK.Java.APIClient 15.0.0

**Source Code**

```
    // build the connector using an access token
    V1Connector connector = V1Connector.withInstanceUrl("https://servername/instancetoauthenticate")
        .withUserAgentHeader("Application", "1.0")
        .withAccessToken("1.WkEciqwKNW7Pnvw9CNmPgQWIdL4=")
        .build();

    // use the connector to instantiate a Services object
    IServices services = new Services(connector);

    // check the logged in member
    Oid oid = services.loggedIn;
    System.out.println("Member Oid: " + oid);
```

**Stack trace**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.versionone.apiclient.exceptions.ConnectionException:
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized error code: 401 Could not authenticate. The VersionOne credentials may be incorrect or the access tokens may have expired.
    at com.versionone.apiclient.V1Connector.manageErrors(V1Connector.java:423)
    at com.versionone.apiclient.V1Connector.getData(V1Connector.java:368)
    at com.versionone.apiclient.Services.retrieve(Services.java:114)
    at com.versionone.apiclient.Services.getLoggedIn(Services.java:254)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodMetaProperty$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MethodMetaProperty.java:73)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:61)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
    at com.netsuite.versionone.exporttasks.Authenticator.main(Authenticator.groovy:30)
```

Comment: Are you able to authenticate with the .withWindowsIntegrated() method?

Comment: Creating the connector with the .withWindowsIntegrated() method works fine. The problem is that we want to connect to the VersionOne instance using an account aside from the one currently logged in to the machine.

Comment: Adding to that, I also tried using the access token of the current windows user but hadn't got it to work.

Comment: Turns out this is a defect with the Java SDK, VersionOne is working on a fix now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the 15.1.0 version of the Java SDK, you can use an access token to connect to a VersionOne instance, even if that instance is configured to use Windows Integrated Authentication. The trick is to use the new useOAuthEndpoints() method of the V1Connector:

```
V1Connector connector = V1Connector
    .withInstanceUrl("<Server Base URI>")
    .withUserAgentHeader("AppName", "1.0")
    .withAccessToken("1.rWM8lKLk+PnyFxkEWVX5Kl2u6Jk=")
    .useOAuthEndpoints()
    .build();
```

Note that you only have to use the useOAuthEndpoints() method for NTLM configured instances.

VersionOne Java SDK connection documentation can be found here: https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/Java_SDK/Creating_a_Connection